# Using DwmIsCompositionEnabled (JwaDwmApi) on pre-vista causes error

Tags: delphi, aero, dwm, jedi-code-library

Been trying to use the following code in order to check if Windows Aero is enabled:

```
function AeroEnabled: boolean;
var
  enabled: bool;
begin
 // Function from the JwaDwmapi unit (JEDI Windows Api Library)
 DwmIsCompositionEnabled(enabled);
 Result := enabled;

end;

 ...

 if (CheckWin32Version(5,4)) and (AeroEnabled) then
 CampaignTabs.ColorBackground   := clBlack
 else begin
 GlassFrame.Enabled             := False;
 CampaignTabs.ColorBackground   := clWhite;
 end;
```

However, doing so on a pre-vista machine causes the app to crash because the DWMApi.dll is missing. I've also tried [this code](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/detect-aero-glass-using-delphi/) however it produces 2 AV's in a row. How can I do this ? I am using Delphi 2010. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got your versions wrong. Vista/2008 server are version 6.0. Your test should be:

```
CheckWin32Version(6,0)
```

I believe that you are using Delphi 2010 or later in which case you should simply call the `DwmCompositionEnabled` function from the built-in `Dwmapi` unit. This organises the version check and the delayed binding for you. No need for JEDI.

---

**Edit:** Text below was written before the question was edited.

Probably the easiest approach is to check the Windows version. You need `Win32MajorVersion>=6` (i.e. Vista or 2008 server) in order to call `DwmIsCompositionEnabled`.

If you were binding yourself then you would call `LoadLibrary` with `DWMApi.dll` and if that succeeded you would then call `GetProcAddress` to bind. If that succeeded you are good. But, as I said, since you aren't handling the binding yourself then a version check is probably the simplest.

So the function would be:

```
function AeroEnabled: boolean;
var
  enabled: bool;
begin
  if Win32MajorVersion>=6 then begin
    DwmIsCompositionEnabled(enabled);
    Result := enabled;
  end else begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Note, I'm assuming that your library is doing late binding, i.e. explicit linking. If not then you'll need LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress, exactly as is done in @RRUZ's code to which you link.