# How to detect Windows Aero theme on Delphi 7?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, aero

How do you detect that the user is running the Windows Aero theme on his operating system by code on Delphi 7?

Comment: If you want to know if the current application is themed, you can simply check `ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled`.

Comment: There's also `DwmCompositionEnabled` in dwmapi.pas.

Comment: > If you want to know if the current application is themed, you can simply check ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled - But if it is themed by Windows 7 Simplified Style or by Windows XP?

Comment: Yeah, your Delphi version was quite relevant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539812/using-dwmiscompositionenabled-jwadwmapi-on-pre-vista-causes-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function we need to use is `Dwmapi.DwmIsCompositionEnabled`, but that is not included in the Windows header translations that ship with Delphi 7 and was added in Vista, released after Delphi 7. Also it crashes the application on Windows XP - so call it after check `if Win32MajorVersion >= 6`.

```
function IsAeroEnabled: Boolean;
type
  TDwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc = function(out pfEnabled: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
var
  IsEnabled: BOOL;
  ModuleHandle: HMODULE;
  DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc: TDwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Win32MajorVersion >= 6 then // Vista or Windows 7+
  begin
    ModuleHandle := LoadLibrary('dwmapi.dll');
    if ModuleHandle <> 0 then
    try
      @DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc := GetProcAddress(ModuleHandle, 'DwmIsCompositionEnabled');
      if Assigned(DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc) then
        if DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc(IsEnabled) = S_OK then
          Result := IsEnabled;
    finally
      FreeLibrary(ModuleHandle);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @TLama - What I posted is a VCL function: `DwmCompositionEnabled`. It calls DwmIsCompositionEnabled only on Vista+, returns false otherwise.

Comment: @Sertac, sorry. My mistake. I'll rather stop doing two things at once :-) Taking back my comment (deleting)... And since the question become tagged as Delphi 7, this is the right answer.

Comment: @TLama - My comment doesn't prove you wrong. I just wanted to be a little specific.

Comment: You need to `FreeLibrary` when `aDllHandle <> 0`

Comment: Otherwise FreeLibrary will fail with 'specified module could not be found', but no one is checking the return so doesn't matter much.